# Bash script add variable to alias

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run this script -

```
#!/bin/bash

my_opts="-2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o FallBackToRsh=no -q -i /root/.ssh/identity"
alias ssh='ssh $my_opts'

type ssh
```

It is giving me the output as `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh`. What needs to be changed so that the output is  - `ssh -2 -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -o 'FallBackToRsh no' -i /root/.ssh/identity`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String interpolation does not happen when you use `'`. Try `"` instead.

Comment: Also, aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells in bash, unless you `shopt -s expand_aliases`. Use a function instead.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Modifying `alias ssh='ssh $sshopts'` to `alias ssh="ssh $sshopts"` didn't make any difference. The output was same.

Comment: What are you trying to do? For what you show, the fix would be to just run `ssh` with the options directly. Why the indirections?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the alias, and define a function.

```
ssh () {
    command ssh -2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o FallBackToRsh=no -q -i /root/.ssh/identity "$@"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

By using ' you are creating a literal string also know in many languages as string as a literal - bash is no exception. Or known as a string interpol. You need to use " in order to pass a var through a string unless you surround the bar with ' like so

`alias install='install '$var''`

Reference
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html

Also making sure you're using `source` e.g. `source ./script.sh` on your script and not running using `bash ./script.sh` when typing the command

Comment: That's not the problem here; using single-quotes prevents the variable from expanding when the alias gets defined, but instead it gets expanded when the alias is used. Also, your example leaves `$var` unquoted in the definition command, which can cause trouble (depending on which shell is used, and what the variable's value is).

Comment: @GordonDavisson https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html says otherwise

Comment: That only applies when the alias is defined (i.e. when the `alias` command is executed). But the quotes are removed during processing of that `alias` command, so they aren't included in the actual alias, so when the alias gets *used* they aren't there. Try running (in an interactive shell) `var=initialval`, then `alias foo='echo $var'`, then `var=otherval`, and finally `foo` (note that you should run them one-at-a-time rather than as a single line with semicolons, because the order of expansion gets weird in a single line). Then try with `alias foo='echo '\''$var'\'` and note the difference.

Comment: The OP's core problem is that aliases are not expanded in a script (that is, when the shell is not interactive), _by default_. Quotes are not relevant to the core issue here.

Comment: @CharlesPorth, if the OP were getting to a place where this was relevant, the output of `type ssh` in their script would be something like `ssh is aliased to 'ssh $my_opts'` (and your answer would be focused on changing the `my_opts` to the actual code with options added). But the problem this answer fixes is not the problem the OP has.

Comment: @CharlesPorth, ...the other thing is that `alias install='install '$var''` is exceedingly silly -- it's a needlessly wordy and slightly buggy way to say `alias install="install $var"` (buggy because the contents of `$var` are expanded unquoted and thus unprotected from word-splitting or glob expansion). It would be less incorrect to write `alias install='install '"$var"`, but still rather silly.